# How do I print the shifted characters in main body?

Tags: c

As it is now, my program does exactly what I need it to do, but I would like the printing done in the `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` void functions to happen in the main body and only have those respective functions either add or subtract the value of shift to be printed in the main body. I was told that the functions are only meant to shift the value of the string characters.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 #define SIZE 500

    int getUserChoice();
    int getShift();
    void getString(char buf[]);
    void encrypt(char buf[], int shift);
    void decrypt(char buf[], int shift);

    int main()
    {
        int shift = 3;
        int userChoice;
        char inputBuf[SIZE] = {0};

    do
    {
        userChoice = getUserChoice();

        switch (userChoice)
        {
            case 1:
                shift = getShift();
            break;

            case 2:
                getString(inputBuf);
                encrypt(inputBuf, shift);
            break;

            case 3:
                getString(inputBuf);
                decrypt(inputBuf, shift);
            break;

            case 4:
                    printf("Thank you for using the program!\n");
                break;

            default:
                printf("Invalid Entry, please try again!");
            break;
        }
    } while(userChoice != 4);

    //printf("Thank you for using the program!\n");

    return 0;
}

int getUserChoice()
{
    //ask about getting single digit user input from Tyler!!!
    int userChoice = 0;

    //char userChoice[1] = {0};

    puts("");
    puts("");

    printf("-------------------------------\n"
           "| 1) Change Shift (default 3) |\n"
           "| 2) Encrypt a message        |\n"
           "| 3) Decrypt a message        |\n"
           "| 4) Quit                     |\n"
           "-------------------------------\n");

    printf("Option: ");
    scanf("%d", &userChoice);
    getchar();

    return userChoice;
}

int getShift()
{
    int shift;

    printf("Enter new shift value: ");
    scanf("%d", &shift);
    getchar();

    return shift;
}


void getString(char inputBuf[])
{
    int num1;
    printf(" Input: ");
    fgets(inputBuf, SIZE, stdin);
    sscanf(inputBuf,"%d\n", &num1);
}


void encrypt(char inputBuf[], int shift)
{

    int len = strlen(inputBuf) - 1;

    printf("%s", "Output: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < len && inputBuf[i] != '\0' ; i++)
    {
        if (inputBuf[i] != 32)
        {
            printf("%c", (inputBuf[i] - shift));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s", " ");
        }
    }

}

void decrypt(char inputBuf[], int shift)
{
    int len = strlen(inputBuf) - 1;

    printf("%s", "Output: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < len && inputBuf[i] != '\0' ; i++)
    {
        if (inputBuf[i] != 32)
        {
            printf("%c", (inputBuf[i] + shift));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s", " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you subtract 1 from `strlen(inputBuf)`?

Comment: There's no need to check `inputBuf[i] != '\0'`, since you're using `len` as the limit of the loop. `strlen()` counts the characters before the null terminator.

Comment: Instead of printing the character, just assign it back to the array element. `inputBuf[i] = inputBuf[i] - shift;`

Comment: @Barmar It has to have a specific limit of 500 characters, I thought I would put "-1" to account for the null characters.

Comment: `strlen()` doesn't count the null character. `"abc"` uses 4 bytes because of the null, but `strlen("abc")` returns `3`.

Comment: @Barmer Once I have modified the array, how do I reference in main function to print?

Comment: `inputBuf` is being modified in place, so just print it.